# UIView subclass bounds incorrect in console

Tags: ios, uiview

Here i have created UIView subclass named as CustomSlider. CustomSlider   added on Storyboard and connected with storyboard outlet reference. When i am printing the bounds, I am having issues with printing the bounds, its providing incorrect console output.

```
 class CustomSlider: UIView {

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        }
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.setupView()
        }
        func setupView()  {
            print("self.bounds.height \(self.bounds)" )
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }


class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: CustomSlider?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider?.setupView()
    }
}
```

When i am trying to build the output bounds displaying as below :

```
self.bounds.height (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 1000.0)
```

But i'm setting constraints trailing, top, right, height. I have tried below line also.

```
slider?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

### here is screenshot my project looks like

[image: here is screenshot my project looks like]

My expected console output would be the slider bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to print the `bounds` comes too soon. A view being loaded from a xib/storyboard has bogus bounds (as shown) until *layout* has occurred. Layout has *not* occurred at the time of `viewDidLoad`; the view is not yet in the interface and *no* sizes are real yet. Postpone your access to `bounds` until at least after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called for the first time.